# Is it possible nowadays to change apply plugin or buildscript dependencies based on flavors?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I saw a few answers that basically you can't do this without some ugly workarounds but pretty much all those answers are several years old. I just want to make sure that there isn't anything new on `Gradle` that would allow me to have `apply plugin` or `buildscript dependencies` be different based on different flavors.

Thanks,

Comment: Typically you would always apply a plugin and it would provide you with a DSL to turn itself on or off conditionally. And of course it would create properties and tasks lazily to be efficient. What you're referring to could be done using project properties (passed e.g. as command line arguments) but that doesn't map 1:1 to flavors so yeah, "ugly workarounds". Speaking of, please link the sources you've already seen.

Comment: When you say `passed as command line`, can I do that on AS somehow when I select the flavor or choose as I select the flavor? I'm basically trying to build for other stores as well but don't want to disrupt my build process as much as possible.

Comment: There's no direct mapping. AS will run some specific Gradle tasks when you click Run. In your script you could check if the task names have been specified in the command line. The problem is when you're not running the `package<flavor>` or `assemble<flavor>` tasks and want to do something smaller. You're only making it hard for yourself to debug when the plugins are and are not applied. Why don't you say what the plugins are, how does the setup differ, in what conditions, and we'll try to work with that.

Comment: In this particular case it is for HMS services from Huawei. But I want to release to several stores and I'm guessing a lot of them will have their little gradle requirements. I have handled most of it via flavors but the `apply plugin` and `buildscript dependencies` I have not been able to figure out.

Comment: Common `buildscript` dependencies are fine, that's just what plugins you _can_ apply later. At this point I would extract all the common code to a library module and create two separate app modules, one for GMS and one for HMS. Since it's separate modules they can have separate plugins applied. Remove duplicate code in build scripts by extracting it to another `*.gradle` file or make your own Gradle plugin if you're feeling fancy.

Comment: Ok cool, so that wouldn't be too difficult to do, thank you.